# How to pass the XML as a url in DOMParser

Tags: document, dom

I found the following details from the [Reading and Writing XML Using the DOM](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_xml_dom.htm) in online salesforce.

As in the page shows, following one is XML file.

```
<address>
    <name>Kirk Stevens</name>
    <street1>808 State St</street1>
    <street2>Apt. 2</street2>
    <city>Palookaville</city>
    <state>PA</state>
    <country>USA</country>
</address>
```

The following one is DomDocument class.

```
public class DomDocument {
 
    // Pass in the URL for the request
    // For the purposes of this sample,assume that the URL
    // returns the XML shown above in the response body
    public void parseResponseDom(String url){
        Http h = new Http();
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        // url that returns the XML in the response body
        req.setEndpoint(url);
        req.setMethod('GET');
        HttpResponse res = h.send(req);
        Dom.Document doc = res.getBodyDocument();
        
        //Retrieve the root element for this document.
        Dom.XMLNode address = doc.getRootElement();
        
        String name = address.getChildElement('name', null).getText();
        String state = address.getChildElement('state', null).getText();
        // print out specific elements
        System.debug('Name: ' + name);
        System.debug('State: ' + state);
        
        // Alternatively, loop through the child elements.
        // This prints out all the elements of the address
        for(Dom.XMLNode child : address.getChildElements()) {
           System.debug(child.getText());
        }
    }
}
```

I understood the above class except the two things which listed below. can you please how to achieve them?

1. How to pass the XML file as a url later as a parameter to parseResponseDom() in above class?
2. String name = address.getChildElement('name', null).getText();
   In this line, in the place of namespace why we are giving null value in getChildElement(name,namespace)?

Help is appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: 2. Keith has already addressed. 1. You have to have en external web service exposed where it returns the given xml string (`<address>...</address>`). then you can pass the service url for that and use above code.

Comment: @hivefive 
So,  i can not pass the xml as a url directly with out external service.

Comment: No way. See in the code the incoming url is used to generate an `HttpRequest` and the response is used as the document.

Comment: @hivefive, it might giving some confusion for me. if you do not mind can you provide one simple example which contains URL as the above class contains?

Answer (score 2):

On item 1, not too clear what your problem is, but to call the code with a URL you would use:

```
Strign url = 'https://...';
new DomDocument().parseResponseDom(url);
```

(See the [DOM.Document documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_xml_dom_document.htm) for how to load the XML from a string that might have come from e.g. a static resource.)

On item 2, if the XML doesn't contain namespaces (as yours doesn't) you pass a `null` in place of the namespace.

**PS**

In response to the comment, you can pass the XML as a string in the method argument and load it into the parser like this:

```
public void parseResponseDom(String xml){

    Dom.Document doc = new Dom.Document();
    doc.load(xml);

    //Retrieve the root element for this document.
    Dom.XMLNode address = doc.getRootElement();

    ...
}
```

Comment: HI Keith, Sorry for the late reply. 
As i am asking by item 1 is How we can use XML file as a url.
Can we pass the url like **string url='https://<address><name>Kirk Stevens</name>street1>808 State St</street1><street2>Apt. 2</street2><city>Palookaville</city><state>PA</state><country>USA</country</address>' **
or is there any other way?
Please help me out

Comment: load(xml) will use for loading the xml in Document class. What my doubt is how we can convert/use xml file as ulr format?

Comment: @SantoshKumar If by file you mean a file on some other computer then yes you are correct that that cannot be accessed from the Salesforce server. All you can do is e.g. get user's to manually upload it first as say an attachment; then the server can process it by reading the attachment body.