# Getting Attempt to de-reference a null object in DOMParser in salesforce

Tags: document, dom

I wrote a class which given below.

```
public class DomDocument {

    Public void parseXmlFile(String xml){

        Dom.Document doc=new Dom.Document();
        doc.load(xml);
        Dom.XmlNode node= doc.getRootElement();
        String name= node.getChildElement('Name',null).getText(); // Error is coming here
        String country= node.getChildElement('country',null).getText();
        System.debug(name);
        System.debug(country);

    }
}
```

Actually, i want to work with below xml

```
<address>
    <name>Kirk Stevens</name>
    <street1>808 State St</street1>
    <street2>Apt. 2</street2>
    <city>Palookaville</city>
    <state>PA</state>
    <country>USA</country>
</address>
```

I am trying to execute this class by using execute anonymous. I am getting NullPointer Exception while i have used the above xml file as a string in parseXmlFile(String xml) like below

`parseXmlFile('<address><name>Kirk Stevens</name><street1>808 State St</street1><street2>Apt. 2</street2><city>Palookaville</city><state>PA</state><country>USA</country></address>');`

could anyone help me out in this. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with below code, issue might be with case sensitivity.

```
String name= node.getChildElement('name',null).getText();
```

Comment: Hi @highfive, Can you please answer the following one 

[http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/137481/how-to-pass-the-xml-as-a-url-in-domparser]